# How to include third party library with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

New to Grunt, and have been using it for the first time to combine/minify JS files for a project.

Currently have this (relevant section) in Gruntfile.js:

`concat:
{
    options:
    {
        banner: '<%= banner %>',
        stripBanners: true
    },
    dist:
    {
        src:
        [
            'build/js/sample_file',
            'build/js/another_file.js'
        ],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.build_name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.js'
    }
},
uglify:
{
    options:
    {
        banner: '<%= banner %>'
    },
    dist:
    {
        src: '<%= concat.dist.dest %>',
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.build_name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.min.js'
    }
},`

That's working fine, but I'm not sure how to do the next thing I need. My project requires Hammer.js.

I could just include the library in the concat, but this doesn't seem right to me for 2 reasons. It's already minified (I could get un-minified, but seems a bit of a waste of time when minified already), and it would seem Grunt would be a bit cleverer than this, and could be used to download the latest Hammer library for me?

How do I get Grunt to include a third-party JS library in the uglified code it builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [bower](http://bower.io) for your dependency-management of vendor libraries

use grunt for linting, testing, building

it's not possible to tell you on how to combine these two, as your question is to unspecific.

in general i would use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and some generator to get my project setup. if none of them satisfies your needs, try to learn from them!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - yeoman looks like a good way to go!